# Angular directives don't work with selects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I can't seem to get selects working with Angular directives!  I have two selects, both inside a directive.  I would like for the first select to determine the available options for the second select.

```
Here's a fiddle:
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jordannpotter/hfyUa/

1. Select "Baz" from the "Secondary Select"
2. Select "First" from the "Primary Select"
3. Notice that the "Secondary Select" *goes blank*!!

Of course, if you comment out the directive code (lines 3-9), it works perfectly.

What's going on here, and how do I fix it??

Comment: How do you want the secondary to act when the primary is changed? The available options of the secondary are different based on what the primary is selected. In your example, for "First" primary there will be 3 options in secondary and for the "Second" primary there will be 2 options.
What exactly do you want to happen to the secondary when primary is changed?

Comment: From line 24, `$scope.secondary = $scope.secondaryOptions[0]` it should set the select to the first available option o_0

Comment: Note that it works perfectly if you comment out lines 3-9 :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you have happening is that the scope of your directive is detaching you from the scope of your controller and you need to add an object level prior to the primary and secondary variables.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])

app.directive('awesomeDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        template: '<div class="awesome" ng-transclude></div>'
    }
});

AwesomeController = function ($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.options = {};
    updateAllowedSecondaryOptions = function () {
        if ($scope.options.primary == 'primaryOption1') {
            $scope.secondaryOptions = [
                {value: 'foo', title: 'Foo'}, 
                {value: 'bar', title: 'Bar'},
                {value: 'baz', title: 'Baz'}]
        } else if ($scope.options.primary == 'primaryOption2') {
            $scope.secondaryOptions = [ 
                {value: 'bar', title: 'Bar'},
                {value: 'baz', title: 'Baz'}]
        }

        $scope.options.secondary = $scope.secondaryOptions[0]
    }

    $scope.options.primary = 'primaryOption2'
    updateAllowedSecondaryOptions()

    $scope.primarySelected = function (newValue) {
        $scope.options.primary = newValue;
        updateAllowedSecondaryOptions()
    }
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/G5PLL/

You can see more about what is happening by reading https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes which goes into what is happening to detach you from the prototypal inheritance.

*P.S. Misko's rule “Whenever you have ng-model there’s gotta be a dot in there somewhere. If you don’t have a dot, you’re doing it wrong.”*